# Ошибка в telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

код:

```
process.env["NTBA_FIX_319"] = 1;
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = '***token from botfather';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    var weather = "погода";
    if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().includes(weather)){
        var requestURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kharkiv,%20UA,%20ru&APPID=***';
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', requestURL);
        request.responseType = 'json';
        request.send();

         request.onload = function() {
            var weather = request.response;
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Ветер " + weather.wind.speed + " м/с"); 

        };
    }
});
```

При запуске (пишу боту "погода") в терминале error: [polling_error] (). Ошибка возникает от xmlhttprequest. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Уверены что от xmlhttprequest? у данного пакета есть issues на github с похожими ошибками

Comment: Замена токена привела от ETELEGRAM: 409 просто к polling error. А запрос создает поток. Когда я удаляю код между if и send message ошибка возникает от var request = new XMLHttpRequest();. Просто предположение